# How to find a string which is not completely known in a text file and replace it in matlab?

Tags: matlab, text, replace, find

I have a a fairly large text file  in which a string like the following one is repeated 50 times.

```
NODE LABEL="NODE-1", LENGTH=(0.001,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
```

The only difference between these repeated strings is the first number after the `=(`.

I mean the strings are as follows:

```
NODE LABEL="NODE-1", LENGTH=(0.001,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-2", LENGTH=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-3", LENGTH=(0.067,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
```

I have a vector like the following one in MATLAB:

```
d =[0.010
    0.120
    0.140]
```

Firstly, I want to identify those lines that contain the above strings. Then, I need to replace the first number in each line of the text file with the corresponding number in the vector `d`.
It means that, my output text file would look like  to :

```
Bla Bla Bla Bla
NODE LABEL="NODE-1", LENGTH=(0.010,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
Bla Bla Bla Bla
Bla Bla Bla Bla
NODE LABEL="NODE-2", LENGTH=(0.012,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
Bla Bla Bla Bla
NODE LABEL="NODE-3", LENGTH=(0.014,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
```

How can I do it?

The essence of my question is that, how to find a string like `LENGTH=(NUMBER,` in a text file, while the `NUMBER` is not known.

Comment: Look up regular expressions. You can use them for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In your question it is not clear id the input file can contains lines not having the "LENGTH=(" string.

I assume it can.

Given the format of the input file lines you've specified, you can:

- check for the presence of the "LENGTH=(" string using `findstr`
- find the position in the line of the number to be replaced, again using `findstr`
- replace the portion of the string with a number fron "d" array converting it to a string

This approach has been implemented in the following code; also a check on the number of values in the "d" array with respect to the number of line to be modified has been added.

I've used an input file containing lines without the "LENGTH=(" string; in this case, the original string is written in the OUTPUT file.

**Input file**

```
NODE LABEL="NODE-1", LENGTH=(0.001,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-2", LENGTH=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-3", WIDTH=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-4", XXXX=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-5", YYYYYYYY=(0.067,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-6", LENGTH=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
```

**The script**

```
% Define the array with replacing values
d =[0.010
   0.120
   0.140];
% Get the number of possible replaceable input file strings
n_val=length(d);
% Open INPUT and OUTPUT files
fp_in=fopen('in_file.txt','rt')
fp_out=fopen('out_file.txt','wt')
% Initialize counter
cnt=1;
% Read the input file line by line
while(1)
   tline = fgetl(fp_in)
   if(ischar(tline))
      % If current input line contains the "LENGTH=(" string, try to
      % replace the number
      if(findstr(tline,'LENGTH=('))
         % If "d" array does not contains enough values, generate error
         % message
         if(cnt > n_val)
            error('Not enough values in "d" array')
         end
         % Replace the number in the string with a value from "d" array
         b=findstr(tline,'(')
         c=findstr(tline,',')
         tline(b+1:c(2)-1)=sprintf('%4.3f',d(cnt))
         % Print the modified line in the OUTPUT file
         fprintf(fp_out,'%s\n',tline)
         % Increment the counter
         cnt=cnt+1
      else
         % If the current line does not contains the "LENGTH=(" string,
         % writhe the line in the OUTPUT file as it is 
         fprintf(fp_out,'%s\n',tline)
      end
   else
      % Stop reading INPUT file
      break
   end
end
% Close INPUT and OUTPUT files
fclose(fp_in);
fclose(fp_out);
```

**Output file**

```
NODE LABEL="NODE-1", LENGTH=(0.010,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-2", LENGTH=(0.120,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-3", WIDTH=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-4", XXXX=(0.005,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-5", YYYYYYYY=(0.067,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
NODE LABEL="NODE-6", LENGTH=(0.140,0.69, 1.805, 5, 10, \
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, It works properly. what is the difference between opening the output  file with permissions 'w' and 'wt'?. when I use the first one, lines are printed successively in the output file on the same line. while, using the last permission prints tline on the next (new) line.

Comment: Addind `t` specifies that the file has to be opened in `text mode`. This should not be the respinsible for the fact your output is written on a single line. On `write` adding `t` implies inserting a carriage return before any newline character in the output (ref. to [fopen documentation)](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html).